# sign and approve all transactions with connected ledger wallet

Tags: transactions, solana-wallet-adapter, ledger, signing, sign

how can I make ledger approve/sign multiple transactions at once?

I'm using Solana wallet adapter for the browser, and for ledger users, they have to approve each transaction even when invoking the providers `signAllTransactions` method.

I read about blind signing for hardware wallets but that seems like it doesn't fix this when it's turned on.

is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Ledgers require that all transactions be manually approved, and do not provide programmatic access to sign multiple transactions.

If you want to sign many transactions quickly, you're better off using your Ledger to fund a separate hot / throwaway keypair and using that temporarily. When you're done, you can send all the unused funds back to the Ledger.

And to be totally clear, you're correct that blind signing doesn't solve the problem. Blind signing only allows you to sign transactions that the Ledger doesn't know how to parse.